# Can a DACPAC created from SQL Server 2017 be published to a SQL Server 2016 environment?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, sql-server-2017, dacpac

Im creating a DACPAC from a SQL Server 2017 database for a client using SQL 2016.  They cannot publish this DACPAC (error: A project which specifies SQL Server vNext CTP as the target platform cannpt be published to Sql Server 2016).
Is it possible to create a backwards compatible DACPAC in SQL 2017?
Im currently using Command Prompt to create and publish the DACPAC.

Comment: *"SQL Server vNext CTP"*? That very strongly implies you're using a very old **pre-release** version of SQL Server 2017. I would not suggest trying to use a DACPAC designed to be used against a **CTP** version of SQL Server against a old release version; it will very likely have unexpected consequences. Why not just change the target platform in the project?

Comment: Thanks for the response Larnu. I have no control over the version of SQL 2017, but Ill raise this if the companies version is a pre-release one.

Comment: Can the target platform be changed in Command prompt? and is this when the DACPAC file is created or published?

Comment: You define the target server in the project, not the DACPAC. So would be in Visual Studio.